# React Native - Remote image overflowing when setting borderRadius

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

Im having a problem configuring a profile image. When a try to round the image using className "roundedfull" from tailwind (I also tried using style: {{borderRadius: 50}}) the component rounds but the image doesn't, it overflows the component:

[image]
[image]

I figured out that if I use a local image it works perfectly:

[image]
[image]

Why it doesn't work with the remote image?